# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Error: Connection id "0HN1QQK58NPAJ"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

when i run my asp.net core web api, in browser show me error 500. and in output window show me this error.

error page is:
[image]

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Error: Connection id "0HN1QQK58NPAJ", Request id "0HN1QQK58NPAJ:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:10809)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

my program file is:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddNodeServices();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
  
}
ArvanStorage_ehsan_simin.AWSAccessKey = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build().GetSection("ArvanStorage:AWSAccessKey").Value;

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Try changing the port number...

Comment: where can i change my app running port default?

Comment: my project running port is : "Now listening on: https://localhost:7263" but error on another port "10809"

Comment: You have a two port application where the frontend is a connection between the client and server and the backend is a connection between the server and a database.  Error 500 is an internal error after the connection completed.  So the connection to local host in the front end is good when you are getting error 500.  So I think the "no connection error" is in the backend (not frontend).  What is the connection string for the backend?

Comment: this is a web api. when run project just swagger must be launch. i edit question and add peogram file code.

Comment: Hi,@ehsanHB,did you run the webapi's .exe file  directly?

Comment: no. i run on https and http (F5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find this answer in visual studio community. [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Running-blazor-web-app-results-in-error/10523449?sort=newest&viewtype=all)

it working by going to Tools → Options → Projects and Solutions → ASP.NET Core and changing the CSS Hot Reload setting to Disabled